# NodeJS external connection error?

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have a problem w my Node Server + Socket Client.
**Well, my localhost server works perfect.**

But... when i connect my socket.io client (node) w my external server (ex: www.myserver.com:3000) doesnt works.

I dont recieve any data. (message var)

This is my sample code:

```
var io = require("socket.io-client");
var requestHTTP = require("request");

  var socket = io('http://myserver.com:3000');
  var room = "game881";

  console.log('test simple socket '+room+'');

  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('conectado', { my: 'Conectado!' });
  });

socket.on('connect', function () {
    socket.emit('room', room);
    console.log('Conectando a ' + room);
  });

  socket.on('message', function (data) {

    var json = data.message;
    json = JSON.parse(json);
    console.log(json);

  });+
```

Why dont recieve any data?

CORS? I've already tried. 
Port used?

:) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... i solved my problem.
**I use this.**

[Setup Server-Server SSL communication using socket.io in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651133/setup-server-server-ssl-communication-using-socket-io-in-node-js)

> The previous answers didn't do it for me. require('https').globalAgent is always >undefined.
>
> Did some seaching and found the rejectUnauthorized parameter in the docs (https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html). Not sure if it's related to SocketIO, but it somehow seems to work with self-signed certificates:
>
> *var socket = io.connect('//yourhost:8000', {secure: true, rejectUnauthorized: false})*
>
> secure: true might be optional, but I like to enforce it anyhow.