# socket.ion, socket.io-clietn, connect

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku

this is hte link on my app:
https://intense-inlet-33140.herokuapp.com/
u can see there what axactly the error I have.

It looks like:

> bundle.js:2391 GET
>   https://intense-inlet-33140.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lt2mQC9
>   404 (Not Found)

the code regarding that I have:
server side app.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
server = require('http').Server(app),
io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Html:

```
script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
```

And bundle.js client side:

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io.connect('https://intense-inlet-33140.herokuapp.com/', {
  'path': '/socket.io/'
});
this.io = socket.connect('/socket.io/', {
  transports: ['websocket'],
  upgrade: false,
});
```

My app running on the Heroku.

What exactly should I put there **io.connect( ??? )**
and there **socket.connect( ??? , {**

I know it must be a path to... socket? I don't understand it well and I tried different options, but there are still the same errors.
Help please.

Comment: Now I have
WebSocket connection to 'wss://intense-inlet-33140.herokuapp.com:5000/socket.io-client/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

changed code to:
var socket = io.connect('https://intense-inlet-33140.herokuapp.com:5000', {
 'path': '/socket.io'
});
this.io = socket.connect('/socket.io-client', {
  transports: ['websocket'],
  upgrade: false
});

Answer (score 0):

First, about your server side:

```
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

You have use port 5000 for WS (not sure you change it to 80 or not)

But in client you connected to WS via PORT 80. So please make sure both of side is same port. Base on your code:

```
var socket = io.connect('https://intense-inlet-33140.herokuapp.com/', {
  'path': '/socket.io/'
});
```

It should replaced by (I remove path because your server not declare custom path, so client don't need do that):

```
var socket = io.connect('https://intense-inlet-33140.herokuapp.com:5000');
```

don't forget open PORT if you have firewall.

Comment: ty a lot for ur answer.
I did what u said.
I mean var socket = io.connect('https://intense-inlet-33140.herokuapp.com:5000');
now I have that arror:


bundle.js:2391 GET https://intense-inlet-33140.herokuapp.com:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lt2yMoM net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: "You have use port 5000 for WS (not sure you change it to 80 or not)"
I dont change it

And now I turned off my firewall, but there are the same errors

Comment: forgot you have connected via SSL. Check this article maybe it help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651133/setup-server-server-ssl-communication-using-socket-io-in-node-js